# Кошмарные шрифты в Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, шрифты

Если использовать 16 кегль шрифта, то он очень  тонкий, а 17-18 то слишком толстый.Можно ли научить oracle java научить использовать системные шрифты? или хотя бы использовать антиалиасинг?

Использовать openjdk  fontfix не советовать, т.к. пробовал,  проблема устраняется но возникает другая проблема, появляются глюки в больших списках - начинают пропадать названия,и еще openjdk становится менее отзывчивая,  появляется задержка в использовании Android studio. 
В **.bashrc** прописанно

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd'
export JAVA_FONTS=/usr/share/fonts/truetype
```

Comment: Уточните операционную систему. По мне так на Windows все шрифты кошмарные, переход на OS X можно вам предлагать? )))

Comment: «oracle java научить использовать системные шрифты» — а причем тут java? Вроде как среда разработки свои настройки имеет.

Comment: Да извиняюсь, не уточнил, дело происходит в linux ubuntu.  Проблема в java  т.к. андроид студия использует её для отрисовки интерфейса, косвенно мои догадки подверджает, то что  я находил схожую проблему  в других   средах разработки написанных на java это net beans, pycharm